# Как сделать прокрутку RecyclerView за пределы последнего элемента?

Tags: android

Как сделать, чтобы RecyclerView прокручивался дальше, за пределы последнего элемента? То есть, когда я достиг последнего элемента, я хочу прокрутить этот последний элемент еще выше, а снизу чтобы было пустое место?

Comment: Попробуйте paddingBottom добавить для RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать android:clipToPadding="false" в комбинации с padding, этот атрибут вместо обычного применения ко всему виду, применяет отступ только к конечным элементам.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:clipToPadding="false"
     android:paddingBottom="100dp" />
```